# Jersey: Is there a way in a bean to put @QueryParam and @FormParam on same bean?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am creating a REST API and in one endpoint properties are supposed to come as QUERY parameters and in another request same properties are supposed to come either as headers or FORM parameters. Is there a way to define @QueryParam and @FormParam in same field inside a bean which I will use in Resource method as @BeanParam

Comment: Why is this required ?

Comment: It is required as I have two resources one has GET and another has POST but the parameters are exactly same

Comment: @dvsakgec I know this is a long time ago, but have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible. You can use the following:

```
public void foo (@QueryParam("bar") String bar1, @FormParam("bar") String bar2) {
    String bar = isEmpty (bar1) ? bar2 : bar1;
}
```

Comment: I already knew this but this doesn't look clean approach, that is reason we use @BeanParam in first place

Comment: @BeanParam looks a lot cleaner than my approach. I don't there is another approach.